# Is it possible to dynamically convert currency symbol from currency code like 'EUR' or 'GBP'?

Tags: php

I would like to get currencies symbols depending on currency codes supplied. For example if given 'EUR', I would like to get € dynamically and if I have 'USD' I get $ automatically in PHP.

NB: I'm actually working on e107 framework

Comment: You can always create an array of currency codes & symbols by yourself. (a quick google lead me to this gist: https://gist.github.com/benedict-w/5644085)

Comment: You asked the same low-quality question already a day ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283265/ If your questions get closed, then please make an actual effort to improve them, instead of just posting the same thing again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to dynamically get currency symbol depending on currency code like 'EUR' or 'GBP'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283265/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-get-currency-symbol-depending-on-currency-code-lik)

Answer (score 0):

if you can use third party libraries, maybe this : 
https://github.com/symfony/Intl
 Can solve your problem, witht the synthax :

```
Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('USD')
```

For example.